# Huggingface Translate Pipe with custom BeamScorer

Tags: huggingface-transformers, machine-translation, encoder-decoder, text-generation

I want to generate a sentence from a machine translation model with constrained decoding that requires a custom `BeamScorer`. Is there a way how to replace the standard `BeamSearchScorer` while using the high-level API such as the Translate pipeline or the `generate` method without explicitly calling the `beam_search` method explicitly?